# Polynomial identity with binomials

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I am trying to show that$$(1 + x + x^2 +x ^3)^p = \sum_{n \ge 0} \sum_{m=0}^{n} {p \choose m}{p \choose n - 2m}x^n$$

I tried $(1 + x + x^2 + x^3)^p = (\frac{1-x^4}{1-x})^p  = (1-x^4)^p (1-x)^{-p}$ following $$(1-x^4)^p = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (-1)^j  {p \choose j}x^{4j} \quad \text{and} \quad (1-x)^{-p} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} {p+i-1 \choose p-1} x^i$$
I am not sure if thats the correct way so any help is appreciated

Comment: I am not sure if this is helpful, but maybe a good approach:  A term of the LHS is going to be $$(1)^a(x)^b(x^2)^c(x^3)^d = x^{b+2c+3d}$$ where $$a+b+c+d=p$$ So you are looking for $b+2c+3d=n$. Can you use that to count how many ways there are to choose the various values  for $a,b,c,d$? Perhaps you can come up with a combinatorial argument rather than a generating function argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $$1+x+x^2+x^3=(1+x)(1+x^2)$$

Comment: Thank you for the input. When im using the binomial theorem im stuck with the sum over x^{2k} and i cant simplify it to the expected formula. Could you elaborate more please

Comment: $$ \begin{align}  (1+x)^{p}(1+x^2)^p&=\sum_{i=0}^{p}\sum_{j=0}^p\binom pi\binom pj x^{i+2j}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^{3p}x^n\sum_{i+2j=n}\binom pi\binom pj \end{align}  $$ So $j$ can go from $0$ to $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ and $i=n-2j.$

Answer (score 3):

We can also start from the right-hand side and transform it to obtain the left-hand side. Since $n$ occurs in only one binomial coefficient, a starter is to exchange the sums and try to continue this way.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}}&\color{blue}{ \sum_{m=0}^{n} \binom{p}{m}\binom{p}{n-2m}x^n}
> =\sum_{0\leq m\leq n<\infty} \binom{p}{m}\binom{p}{n-2m}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\binom{p}{m}\binom{p}{n-2m}x^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\binom{p}{m}\sum_{n=2m}^{\infty}\binom{p}{n-2m}x^n\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\binom{p}{m}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{p}{n}x^{n+2m}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\binom{p}{m}\left(x^2\right)^m\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{p}{n}x^{n}\tag{5}\\
> &=\left(1+x^2\right)^p(1+x)^p\tag{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(1+x+x^2+x^3\right)^p}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use a convenient notation to better see the change of summation in the following line.
- In (2) we exchange the summation order.
- In (3) we factor out $\binom{p}{m}$ and start the inner sum with $n=2m$ noting that $\binom{\alpha}{k}=0$ if $k < 0$.
- In (4) we shift the index of the inner sum to start with $n=0$.
- In (5) we factor out $x^{2m}$.
- In (6) we observe we can apply the binomial theorem twice noting the upper index of both sums is $p$ since other terms with $m,n>p$ vanish.